# I want an image and link to only show to people located in USA and Australia on my website, how to do this?

Tags: html

I'm using 2 different CMS, WordPress and MyBB. I've searched for the answer but can find it nowhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you searched for Geo Targeting?

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because the solutions required are those in programming nature, coding based or requests for resources are off-topic.

is more suited for Stack Overflow (SO).

Answer (score 2):

You can roughly target people by nationality by checking their browser setting in JavaScript:

```
if (navigator.languages.includes("en-US") ||
    navigator.languages.includes("en-AU")) {
    // show the image and link
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages

There are also ways of getting people's location using geo-lookup. Ideas here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript

It may be easiest to just find plugins to do what you want, though.